# How to unzip .ZIP mime type (application / x-zip-compressed) in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types, unzip

I have the following problem, I am developing a process that unzips and validates the files inside a .zip in a google drive folder, the problem is that these .zips are type Mime **(application / x-zip-compressed)** and the method ** unzip ** does not seem to recognize this type of Mime, since the **(application / zip)** does work correctly.

I enclose the example code:

```js
function unZipIt() {
  var theFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Id de la carpeta')
  var fileBlob = theFile.next().getBlob()

  fileBlob.setContentType("application/x-zip-compressed")

  var unZippedfile = Utilities.unzip(fileBlob)
Logger.log(unZippedfile);
  }
```

The exception thrown in the line `var unZippedfile = Utilities.unzip (fileBlob)` is the following:

```
**Exception: Converting from application/x-zip-compressed to application/zip is not supported.**
```

My question is: How can I decompress or iterate the files inside these Zip with type Mime: ** application / x-zip-compressed ** or how can I convert to ** application / zip **?

Note: Sorry if there is bad writing, I am using translator.

Thanks

Comment: How are those zip files created? Also, have you tried changing the `setContentType` to zip?

Comment: I created these files in Windows 10 and uploaded them to the drive I tried with `setContentType` to` application / zip` but it throws me the following error: `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property unzip on object Utilities`

Comment: Although from your script, I cannot understand about `theFile`, for example, when `setContentTypeFromExtension()` is used instead of `setContentType("application/x-zip-compressed")`, what result will you obtain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [setContentTypeFromExtension](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypefromextension) as @Tanaike has suggested:

```
var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newestFileId);
var thisBlob = thisFile.getBlob();
var convertedBlob = thisBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension();
var thisUnzip = Utilities.unzip(convertedBlob);
```